# why on click of popup remove focus from formView?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one Form which contain user name and password.so, i validate if both the field have none value then pop as "please enter username and password".i make on custom popup using div.my question is i put my focus on username field.so currently i focused to username.but username have not any value then i pressed submit button so, i get my custom pop up "please enter username and password".after i click on my custom pop up area.then username focus is removed.why?i want to get same focused on username while any where i click on popup.

Comment: Put focus explicitly then

Comment: my question is my focus shouldn't be change in form,while on pop up open.or click any where of pop up area.

Comment: If you click out of text box then the focus is shifted to where ever you click, hence its lost on the text box. You must use Jquery to either stop this focus loss or add the focus back on to the text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('username-field-selector').focus();
```

This should set the focus back to the selected field. 
When you click on the submit button the focus go from that input element to the button that is why you lose your focus.

Comment: my question isn't to set focus but focus shouldn't be change in form,while on pop up open.or click any where of pop up area

Comment: @Vasant can you please the code that opens the popup.

Comment: i used sweet alert.

Comment: I am not familiar with this library so i would like to see your code.

Comment: i just use swal(a) for alert because i used sweet alert js and css.i want same functionality which is run in native alert.do you have any custom alert link which is working like native alert.on press of native alert focus doesn't remove from form element.